# Problems setting Python path for Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, macos, enthought, canopy

I am running Mac OSX 10.9.5. I'm trying to use Enthought Canopy as my IDE, but want it to point to the Python distribution that I installed using Homebrew. I followed the instructions on [this](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-) page, to no avail.

Here's what I did:

When I type 'which python' into Terminal, I get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Hence, I modified the 'launchd.conf' file to include the following:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

The launchd.conf information appears to be going through, because when I type 'export', I get the following:

```
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
declare -x PWD="/Users/***/.canopy"
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!!

P.S. I don't know if it's relevant or not, but I have the below information in my ~/.canopy/locations.cfg file:

```
{'canopy_64bit-system': u'/Users/****/Documents/System', 'canopy_64bit-user': u'/Users/***/Documents/User'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but want [Canopy] to point to the Python distribution that I installed using Homebrew.

You cannot do this safely. This is not supported yet. At the moment, the Canopy IDE is inseparably linked to the Python distribution on which it is based (with which it installs). Less fundamentally impossible but still fragile and not supported would be using PYTHONPATH to allow Canopy Python to import packages from inside your existing Python. If you want to share a module or package between several python distributions, keep the source of the package outside of any of the distributions, and install it into each of them separately.

Comment: That's too bad.  Thanks!

Comment: However, I am a bit confused about the instructions posted on the following link: 

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

It seems to imply that it is possible to change the environmental variables for Canopy?  Fundamentally, I don't really care whether Canopy is running its own version of Python or the one I downloaded, but I would like to keep my libraries in one place.

Comment: That's right. The article links to two threads on Stack Overflow that describe how to set environment variables in apps (like Canopy) that are launched from MacOS desktop, spotlight, etc.

Comment: But don't environment variables contain the Python path?  So if /usr/local/bin is in the environment variables shouldn't Canopy point to that location when looking for Python?  Sorry--I'm so confused!

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not the same as PATH.  PATH is where the system will look fo executables, and PYTHONPATH is where Python will look for modules.  So telling Python to look in /usr/local/bin wil have no effect because there shouldn't be any Python modules there.  You probably want to add /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages to PYTHONPATH instead, but if there are any extension modules there that are not binary compatible with Canopy's Python then you may have problems with that.  (IOW, the 2 pythons need to be approximately the same version and have been built with compatible flags.)